# Positioning text in different CSS shapes

Tags: html, css

Unfortunately I’m going slightly mad trying to align the “date” numbers over the CSS shapes.  The problem I have is I would prefer a “universal” CSS number format for simplicity (the date is a displayed variable with a class applied to the td). I then change the CSS class for the underlying cell shape depending on its state to give it a background.  All the PHP works to output the thing but some of the numbers align central to the cell, others are too low in the cell (mid height bottom) and two of them are off the page on at the top.

This is where I am up to (very simplified but illustrates the alignment problem in a table) – JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xLWCH/

```
.daynumber  {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#000000; font-weight: bold; position:absolute; display: table-cell; width:20px; vertical-align:middle; top:-9px; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;}

.halfdaystart {position:relative; border-top: 20px solid green; border-right:20px solid red; font-size:0; line-height:0; width:0;}
.halfdayend   {position:relative; border-top: 20px solid red; border-right:20px solid green; font-size:0; line-height:0; width:0;}
.booked {width:20px; height:20px; background:red;}

.Prohalfdaystart {position:relative; border-top:20px solid green; border-right:20px solid yellow; font-size:0; line-height:0; width:0;}
.Prohalfdayend {position:relative; border-top: 20px solid yellow; border-right:20px solid green;font-size:0; line-height:0; width:0;}
.Profree {width:20px; height:20px; background:yellow;}

.SBhalfdaystart {position:relative; border-top:20px solid red; border-right:20px solid green; width:0; height:0;}
.SBhalfdaystart:before {content: ''; display:block; position:relative; background:lightblue; height:5px; width:20px; top:-20px;}

.SBhalfdayend {position:relative; border-top:20px solid green; border-right:20px solid red; width:0; height:0;}
.SBhalfdayend:before { content: ''; display:block; position:relative; background:lightblue; height:5px; width:20px; top:-20px;}

.free {position:relative; width:20px; height:20px; background:green;}

.SBfree {position:relative; border-top:20px solid green; border-right:20px solid green; width:0; height:0;}
.SBfree:before { content: ''; display:block; position:absolute; background:lightblue; height:5px; width:20px; top:-20px;}


<table width="20" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Halfdaystart
<div class='halfdaystart'> <!-- or other corresponding class above  -->
<table width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
<tr>
<td align=center class="daynumber">1</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

What is the best way to do this?  Can it be done with a one size fits all CSS or will I have to create a separate class for the text (applied to the td) as well depending on what I want to display as the div class that controls the shape?  Basically is there a quick and easy way to do this?

Comment: Why are there so many `<table>`s?

Comment: Its for a calendar displayed in a block form. The layout I used emulates this with out all the code that actually builds the calendar. I guess it was originally built back in the days when tables were cool... it certainly makes laying out the days and dates in a grid easy, however its not very malleable

Comment: From the fiddle, it looks like all you're doing is drawing diagonal strips of colour. Maybe you should consider using CSS gradients for this rather than CSS shapes -- it would be a lot less complex and probably easier to work with.